# Looping though A-Z with Do while loop in PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to loop though a-z with a do while loop.
I know that I also can do that with foreach and forloop.

```
$char = 'a';
do {
   echo $char;
   $char++;

} while ($char <= 'z');
```

Why is that giving the output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaaabacadaeafagahaiajakalamanaoapaqarasatauavawaxayazbabbbcbdbebfbgbhbibjbkblbmbnbobpbqbrbsbtbubvbwbxbybzcacbcccdcecfcgchcicjckclcmcncocpcqcrcsctcucvcwcxcyczdadbdcdddedfdgdhdidjdkdldmdndodpdqdrdsdtdudvdwdxdydzeaebecedeeefegeheiejekelemeneoepeqereseteuevewexeyezfafbfcfdfefffgfhfifjfkflfmfnfofpfqfrfsftfufvfwfxfyfzgagbgcgdgegfggghgigjgkglgmgngogpgqgrgsgtgugvgwgxgygzhahbhchdhehfhghhhihjhkhlhmhnhohphqhrhshthuhvhwhxhyhziaibicidieifigihiiijikiliminioipiqirisitiuiviwixiyizjajbjcjdjejfjgjhjijjjkjljmjnjojpjqjrjsjtjujvjwjxjyjzkakbkckdkekfkgkhkikjkkklkmknkokpkqkrksktkukvkwkxkykzlalblcldlelflglhliljlklllmlnlolplqlrlsltlulvlwlxlylzmambmcmdmemfmgmhmimjmkmlmmmnmompmqmrmsmtmumvmwmxmymznanbncndnenfngnhninjnknlnmnnnonpnqnrnsntnunvnwnxnynzoaobocodoeofogohoiojokolomonooopoqorosotouovowoxoyozpapbpcpdpepfpgphpipjpkplpmpnpopppqprpsptpupvpwpxpypzqaqbqcqdqeqfqgqhqiqjqkqlqmqnqoqpqqqrqsqtquqvqwqxqyqzrarbrcrdrerfrgrhrirjrkrlrmrnrorprqrrrsrtrurvrwrxryrzsasbscsdsesfsgshsisjskslsmsnsospsqsrssstsusvswsxsysztatbtctdtetftgthtitjtktltmtntotptqtrtstttutvtwtxtytzuaubucudueufuguhuiujukulumunuoupuqurusutuuuvuwuxuyuzvavbvcvdvevfvgvhvivjvkvlvmvnvovpvqvrvsvtvuvvvwvxvyvzwawbwcwdwewfwgwhwiwjwkwlwmwnwowpwqwrwswtwuwvwwwxwywzxaxbxcxdxexfxgxhxixjxkxlxmxnxoxpxqxrxsxtxuxvxwxxxyxzyaybycydyeyfygyhyiyjykylymynyoypyqyrysytyuyvywyxyyyz
```

instead of just:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: my mind has been blown

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl `$a = 'Z'; $a++;` turns `$a` into `'AA'`, while in C `a = 'Z'; a++;` turns a into `'['` (ASCII value of `'Z'` is 90, ASCII value of `'['` is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported.

Try something like this:

```
for($i = 0, $char = 'a'; $i < 26; $i++, $char++) {
   echo $char;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare `z` with `26` or some kind of number. You need something to compare it with the number. The function [`ord()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) does it. So, you can do something like:

```
$char = 'a';
do {
   echo $char;
   $char++;

} while (ord($char) <= ord('z'));
```

Comment: What about having ord($char) <= ord('z') ?

Answer (score 4):

Because

```
<?php

$char = 'z';

var_dump(++$char); //string(2) "aa"

var_dump('aa' <= 'z'); //bool(true)
var_dump('za' <= 'z'); //bool(false)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/fuhWcLjC)

Personally I'd just use a loop from 97 (ascii value for `a`) to 122 (ascii value for `z`):

```
for ($i = 97; $i <= 122; $i++) {
    echo chr($i);
}
```

Comment: Wow. Nice observation! :D

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above options is the code below.

```
   <?php
    $i = '0';
    while($i < '26') {
    echo chr(97 + $i);
    $i++;
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach(range('a', 'z') as $char) {
    echo "$char ";
}
```

Simple range view a-z.